# Securing Node + Postgres + Passport

Tags: node.js, postgresql, security, passport.js

I'm currently learning node, postgres, and passport but I am not sure on how to secure my application and best practices. I'm not sure on how to sanitize data from client and server or if it's needed but I've parameterized my queries. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Apologies for my newbieness.

```js
var express = require('express');
var helmet = require('helmet')

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var expressSession = require('express-session');

var passport = require('passport');
var passportLocal = require('passport-local');
var pg = require ('pg');
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

var app = express();
app.use(helmet());
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

var config = {
  user: 'REDACTED',
  database: 'REDACTED',
  password: 'REDACTED',
  host: 'REDACTED',
  port: 5432,
  max: 10,
  idleTimeoutMillis: 30000,
};

var pool = new pg.Pool(config);
pool.on('error', function (err, client) {
  console.error('idle client error', err.message, err.stack)
})

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(expressSession( {
  secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET || 'secret',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.use(new passportLocal.Strategy(function(username, password, done) {
  pool.connect(function(poolErr, poolClient, poolDone) {
    if(poolErr) {
      return console.error('pool client fetch error', poolErr);
    }

    poolClient.query('SELECT id, password FROM users WHERE username = $1', [username], function(queryErr, queryRes) {
      if(queryErr) {
        return console.error('query error', queryErr);
      }

      if(queryRes.rows[0] != undefined)
      {
          bcrypt.compare(password, queryRes.rows[0].password, function(compareErr, compareRes) {
            if(compareErr) {
              return console.error('bcrypt error', compareErr);
            }

            if(compareRes) {
                done(null, { id: queryRes.rows[0].id });
            } else {
                done(null, null);
            }

            poolDone();
          });
      } else {
        //user not found
        poolDone();
        done(null, null);
      }
    });
  });
  
}));


passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  pool.connect(function(err, poolClient, poolDone) {
    if(err) {
      return console.error('pool client fetch error', err);
    }

    poolClient.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $1', [id], function(queryErr, queryRes) {
      if(queryErr) {
        return console.error('query error', queryErr);
      }

      if(queryRes.rows[0] != undefined)
      {
        done(null, { id: id, username: queryRes.rows[0].username, firstname: queryRes.rows[0].firstname, lastname: queryRes.rows[0].lastname });
      } else {
        //user not found
 done(null, null);
      }

      poolDone();
    });
  });
  
});

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index', {
    isAuthenticated: req.isAuthenticated(),
    user: req.user
  })
});


app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
  res.render('login');
});

app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), function(req, res) {
  res.redirect('/');
});

app.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
  req.logout();
  res.redirect('/');
});

server.listen(8080);
console.log('Server is running...');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see much problem but here is my 2 cent to improve it.

Use compression to reduce network size

```
app.use(require('compression'));
```

Use serve-static for static file like images or pdf

```
app.use(require('serve-static')('./public'))
```

Use middleware to control end point that need Authentication like view/edit profile, change password and etc

```
function authenticated(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) next();
  else {
    res.status(401).send('User not authenticated.');
    // or redirect to login
  }
}

app.get('/profile', authenticated, function(req, res) {
  res.render('profile', {
    req.user
  })
})
```

Include session destroy when logout

```
app.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
  req.session.destroy();
  req.logout();
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

for sanitizing queries you can use ORM like sequelise